# How to change file names in different folders?

Tags: macos, file, file-transfer

I have lots of files with identical name, say "hello.jpg".

They are located in many folders, say

```
\aaa\hello.jpg
\bbb\hello.jpg
\adaage\hello.jpg
```

I want to change their name to

```
\aaa\aaa_hello.jpg
\bbb\bbb_hello.jpg
...
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can run this command in **Terminal**:

```
find . -name hello.jpg -exec bash -c 'mv "$1" "${1%/*}"/"$(echo $(dirname "$1")_$(basename "$1"))"' -- {} \;
```

This will find all `hello.jpg` files inside directories and prepend dir name in front of the filename. NOTE: this search only inside current dir You're in - not the whole partition.

<sub>EDIT: fixed spaces in dir/filename.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

This is what I find when googling around for batch renaming files, hope it helps you. http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/3-easy-ways-to-batch-rename-files-on-the-mac--mac-46999

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.